# Can't find tkinter AttributeError

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a code for banking system using python and Tkinter. When I run the program I encounter a few errors. Could someone please help me to figure this out. I have done research about it, but can't find a solution to the problem.

Here is the error:

```
 ...File "C:\Users\stjur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2256, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

And here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title('Avis Banking System')
def win1():
    global balance
    balance=600
    global root
    global tries
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Avis banking system')
    entry_1Var=StringVar()
    entry_2Var=StringVar()
    tries=0

tries=0
def CheckPass():
    global tries

    if (tries<3):
        textvalue=entry_1Var.get()
        textvalue=entry_2Var.get()
        if textvalue!=('John123') and textvalue!=('Secret'):
            tries+=1
            label3=Label(root,text='Try again')
            label.grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W,padx=7)
                else:
                    win2()
    if (tries==3):
        label4=Label(root,text='Used all attempts, entry blocked')
        label4.grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W,padx=7)

entry_1Var=StringVar()
entry_2Var=StringVar()
b1=Button(root,text='Login',width=5,command=CheckPass)
b1.grid(row=1,column=10,sticky='e'+'w',padx=7)
b2=Button(root,text='Reset',width=5,)
b2.grid(row=2,column=10,sticky='e'+'w',padx=7)
l1=Label(root,text='Username:').grid(row=1,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='we')
l2=Label(root,text='Password:').grid(row=2,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='we')
e1=Entry(root,width=30,textvariable=entry_1Var)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=2)
e2=Entry(root,show='*',width=30,textvariable=entry_2Var)
e2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=2)
logLabel=Label(root,text='Login',font='bold',fg='Grey')
logLabel.grid(row=0,padx=5,pady=5)
check=Checkbutton(root,text='Keep me logged in')
ckeck.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W,pady=5)

if (tries==3):
    win2

def win2():
    #this is the child window of the main window.
    win2=Toplevel(root)
    win2.minsize(width=400,height=400)
    win2.title("Main Menu")
    #Label for the the main menu
    lb=Label(win2,text='N&E Scotland Bank\nMain   Menu:',bg='#e6e6e6',height=6).pack(fill=X)

     btn_1=Button(win2,text='Make    Deposit',width=15,height=2,command=win3).pack(pady=5)
     btn_2=Button(win2,text='Withdrawal',width=15,height=2).pack(pady=5)
     btn_3=Button(win2,text='Accounts',width=15,height=2).pack(pady=5)
     btn_4=Button(win2,text='Balance',width=15,height=2).pack(pady=5)
     btn_5=Button(win2,text='Exit',width=15,height=2).pack(pady=5)

     def win3():#new window for the button make depost
     win3=Tk()
     win3.title('Make Deposit')
     win3.minsize(width=400,height=120)
     e1=IntVar()
     e2=IntVar()

def MakeDeposit():
    num2 = e2.get()
    balance = int(num2)
    num1 = e1.get()
    depositAmount = int(num1)
    while depositAmount<=0 or depositAmount%10!=0:
       errorLabel = Label(win3,text="That was not a valid amount").grid(row=3,columnspan=5)
       return#
    textLabel = Label(win3,text=("Your new balance is:\n")).grid(row=3,columnspan=5)
    newBalanceLabel = Label(win3,text=(balance+depositAmount)).grid(row=4,columnspan=5, pady=7)

l1=Label(win3,text='Deposit Amount:').grid(row=1,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='we')
l2=Label(win3,text='Balance:').grid(row=2,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='e')
b1=Butto(win3,text='Calculate',width=8,height=3,command=MakeDeposit).grid(row=1,column=10,sticky='e'+'w',padx=7,rowspan=2)
e1=Entry(win3,width=40)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=3)
e2=Entry(win3,width=40)
e2.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky='e'+'w',columnspan=3)
 logLabel=Label(root,text='DEPOSIT',font='bold',fg='Grey').grid(row=0,padx=5,pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see a syntax error in your code.

Comment: You are calling `Tk()` in multiple places.  That does not work, you need to use `Toplevel()` for additional windows.  You are using  `win2` and `win3` as both names of functions, and names of windows created by those functions.  That does not work.

Comment: The error line, 2256, in `tkinter.__init__` is in the private ._setup method of the internal BaseWidget class.   To interpret it, we need to see the full traceback (formatted as code, as you did above) when running the original code, which is not what is posted above.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain the error message.  After fixing the formatting errors in my local copy, I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\mypy\tem.py", line 84, in <module>
    l1=Label(win3,text='Deposit Amount:').grid(row=1,padx=7,pady=5,sticky='we')
  File "C:\Programs\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Programs\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2286, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Programs\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2256, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

The first, parent argument for any Widget creation call must be a widget.  In

```
l1=Label(win3, ...
```

you passed the win3 function, which does not have a `tk` attribute.

For the future, please read about [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).